# temporary name of file uploaded not getting in blueimp jQuery file upload

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter, jquery-file-upload, blueimp

i am using blueimp jQuery file upload for file uploader.This is my controller code.

```
public function savedocument() {
        $response = array('status' => 'failed', 'message' => 'Unknown reason');
        $config = array();
        $config['upload_path'] = 'upload path';
        $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png|pdf|doc|docx';
        $config['max_size']      = '20480';
        $config['overwrite']     = FALSE;
    //var_dump($config);
        $this->load->library('upload', $config);

        $files = $_FILES;
        for($i=0; $i< count($_FILES['files']['name']); $i++)
        {           
        $_FILES['files']['name']= $files['files']['name'][$i];
        $_FILES['files']['type']= $files['files']['type'][$i];
        $_FILES['files']['tmp_name']= $files['files']['tmp_name'][$i];
        $_FILES['files']['error']= $files['files']['error'][$i];
        $_FILES['files']['size']= $files['files']['size'][$i];    

        $this->upload->initialize($config);
    if (!$this->upload->do_upload('files')) {

                $response['message'] = $this->upload->display_errors();
            } else {
              $file_details = $this->upload->do_upload('files');

                     $response['status'] = 'success';
                $response['message'] = $file_details;
    }
        }

    }
```

i am getting the value of printing $file_details as bool(true).The uploaded file name(ie.name assigned by the upload library ) is not working.i want to get those details.how to get it?if anybody knows pls help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$this->upload->do_upload('files');` returns `true` if the file was uploaded correctly. What you want probably is `$this->upload->data()`. Also, I'll suggest changing the name of the file(not necessary but helps in debugging). Below is the working code on this matter -

```
for($i = 0; $i < count($_FILES['files']['name']); $i++){     

    $_FILES['user_file']['name']     = $_FILES['files']['name'][$i];
    $_FILES['user_file']['type']     = $_FILES['files']['type'][$i];
    $_FILES['user_file']['tmp_name'] = $_FILES['files']['tmp_name'][$i];
    $_FILES['user_file']['error']    = $_FILES['files']['error'][$i];
    $_FILES['user_file']['size']     = $_FILES['files']['size'][$i];
    
    $fileName = 'user_file';
}

$config['upload_path']   = 'your-path-here';
$config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|jpeg|png|GIF|JPG|PNG|JPEG';
$config['max_size']      = 6096;
$config['max_width']     = 1024;
$config['max_height']    = 768;
$config['encrypt_name']  = TRUE;
    
$this->load->library('upload', $config);
$this->upload->initialize($config);

$uploaded = $this->upload->do_upload($fileName);
    
if ( ! $uploaded ){
      
    $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());

}else{

    $upload_data = $this->upload->data(); // You'll get all the data of the uploaded file here.
    $file        = $upload_data['file_name'];
}
```

See if it helps you.